# Magento 1 Payment option customization

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, paypal-express

I have a website in Magento 1. I want to limit the credit card purchase to $2000 per customer, per week. If the amount goes over $2000, then they don't see the credit card or the PayPal option, they can only see the bank transfer option.

Is there any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can archive this by hiding the payment methods by observer event.

Please check this tutorial to hide the payment: https://meetanshi.com/blog/disable-payment-method-programmatically-in-magento/

In observer, you have to get the order collection of the current customer and then filter the collection by a particular payment method and calculate the total order amounts.

Now, based on the total amount of order, you can set the conditions and restrict the particular payment methods.

Comment: Hello, can u tell me where i can add condition code?

Comment: In the observer?

Comment: this is my new requirement https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/309187/paypal-express-checkout-customisation-in-magento-1

Comment: can you tell me how i can add minimum order total field in paypal express checkout?

Comment: .Can u please help